# Infinite norm of the inverse of a lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to compute $||B^{-1}||_{\infty}$ for  the square real matrix $B$ s.t. $$b_{ii}=1$$ $$b_{ij}=-1 \quad i<j$$ $$b_{ij}=0 \quad i>j$$

---

I note that $B = I+N$, where $N$ is a lower triangular matrix with all $-1$'s one the lower part. Therefore [(see this question for details)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47543/getting-the-inverse-of-a-lower-upper-triangular-matrix) , it's nilpotent, i.e. $N^n=0$. Hence $$B^{-1}=(I+N)^{-1}=I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kN^k$$

Now it should be easy: I note that in the last row of each of the summand I have more terms, hence I would say that $$||B||_{\infty}=1+ (n-1) + (n-2)+\ldots + 1 = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = 1+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

**The problem is that book says it is equal to $2^{n-1}$**, how is it possible?

Comment: You want to compute $\|B\|_\infty$ or $\|B^{-1}\|_\infty$?

Comment: $||B^{-1}||_{\infty}$

Comment: The problem is that $N^k$ does not have all $1$'s in its last row. It is more complicated than that.

Comment: I just realized it with matlab. Yes, indeed I have things like powers of two, but I don't know how to handle them, I can't see the pattern @StinkingBishop

Comment: @TheSilverDoe beat me to it - the pattern he is showing in his answer is correct. Basically, the last row looks like $\begin{bmatrix}2^{n-2}&2^{n-3}&\cdots&4&2&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and the sum is $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks. In order to see this ,did you try to multiply and see what happens?

Comment: Indeed, I actually did this: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0\\-1&1&0&\cdots&0\\-1&-1&1&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\-1&-1&-1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&\cdots&a_{3n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&a_{n3}&\cdots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&1&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}$, then looked at what $a_{ij}$ could be (i.e. solved the system of equations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$(B^{-1})_{ij} = 0 \text{ if } i> j$$
$$(B^{-1})_{ij} = 1 \text{ if } i= j$$
$$(B^{-1})_{ij} = 2^{j-i-1} \text{ if } i< j$$